# Send unencoded GET requests in Go

Tags: http, go, get

I need to send an **unencoded** GET request to an API which is not conforming to the specs. The destination API doesn't accept encoded URLs, I can only send requests as it is without any query encoding. By default `net/http` encodes requests. I tried this:

```
client := &http.Client{}

req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", `https://api.website.com/rest/v1/item/0?search=[{"key":"tag","value":"myvalue"}]`, nil)

req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer " + viper.GetString("ACCESS_TOKEN"))
response, _ := client.Do(req)
defer req.Body.Close()

data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)
```

I tried to construct my own `Request` and manipulating `RawQuery`, without success. I keep getting a bad request, while if I send the same request through Postman, everything's fine.

EDIT: That's what I tried to do to set the URL myself, and if I print it I can see it's not encoded. The error I get is: `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`.

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "", nil)

req.URL = &url.URL{
    Host:     "api.website.com",
    Scheme:   "https",
    RawQuery: `/rest/v1/item/0?search=[{"key":"tag","value":"myvalue"}]`,
}

req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer " + viper.GetString("RAINDROP_TOKEN"))
res, _ := client.Do(req)
defer req.Body.Close()

data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)
```

Comment: Can you show what you did with RawQuery?

Comment: @BurakSerdar there you go

Comment: RawQuery is only the query, so it should be `search=[{...}]`, that is, the parts after the question mark. Set the path in url.Path field.

Comment: I still can't change anything because I always get pointer errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the protocol and host when creating the request. Set [URL.Opaque](https://godoc.org/net/url#URL.Opaque) to the desired request URI:

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.website.com/", nil)
req.URL.Opaque = `/rest/v1/item/0?search=[{"key":"tag","value":"myvalue"}]`
req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer " + viper.GetString("RAINDROP_TOKEN"))
res, _ := client.Do(req)
defer req.Body.Close()
data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jQqTy5hRgvT).

Comment: understood. I don't understand why postman works fine, and requests without encoded characters work as well, what else can I try?

Comment: @MuffinTop never knew you could write out a request like that! Neat trick.

Comment: Yes this answers the question, and I've found why it wasn't working! The "Unauthorized" message was misleading, the problem is the URI encoding, the comma shouldn't be encoded because the API will give an error, so... yeah, that was irritating. I had to write my encoding function and pass the result to `req.URL.Opaque`.